# Multiple-Line String Initialization

Tags: c++, string, initialization

```
string menu = "\nChoose an option:\n1. Push Front\t2. Push Back\t"
+ "3. Pop Front\t4. Pop Back\n5. Front Value\t6. Back Value\t"
+ 7. Delete Nodes\n8. Clear List\t9. List Size\t10. Print List\t11. Quit\n";
```

I am trying to figure out how to initialize a string that is about 180 characters long, but I want to concatenate it, because I don't want the whole string to appear on just one line. I want to stray away from wrapping lines of code.

Is there a way to do this, because the above method does not work. My example is Java syntax, but I would like to know how to do it in C++. I have search everywhere, please help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove the + signs, the preprocessor will concatenate strings like this:

```
string menu = "\nChoose an option:\n1. Push Front\t2. Push Back\t"
"3. Pop Front\t4. Pop Back\n5. Front Value\t6. Back Value\t"
"7. Delete Nodes\n8. Clear List\t9. List Size\t10. Print List\t11. Quit\n";
```

Comment: Baw, you beat me by 25 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I would get a compile error by doing that.

Comment: is there any advantages by doing this?